# Is this possible to fine tune T5 by changing its configuration using T5Config class object?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, summarization, huggingface-datasets

Trained the "T5-base" as given in the video tutorial of [Venelin Valkov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMyZUIraHio&t=2178s). It is working well. Then I tried to change some configuration like the number of layers (num_layers) and drop out in layers (dropout_rate) using

> config = T5Config(num_layers=8, dropout_rate=0.2)

and then including the config object in

> self.model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("t5-base", config=config, return_dict = True)

as given [here](https://atifkhurshid.medium.com/huggingface-transformers-26ab0ff4b2a4), but it didn't work. It returns an error

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_dict'

Please help.

Comment: As the error message states, the problem seems to be `return_dict = True`, not the `config=config`. What is your expected behavior, or where did you find such a statement?

Comment: The code runs well with "return_dict = True" when I run it without "config=config". The Documentation of  T5ForConditionalGeneration says "return_dict (bool, optional) - Whether or not to return a ModelOutput instead of a plain tuple".

Answer (score 1):

Use this method it works first take the original model config that will be in T5Config class convert it to python dictionary using **.to_dict()**

```
# Define the Flan-T5-base model and tokenizer
check_point = "google/flan-t5-base"
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(check_point)
model_config = model.config.to_dict()
```

After this you can see the model config edit hyperparameter like we edit a dictionary

```
model_config["dropout_rate"] = 0.5
config = T5Config(**model_config)
```

Now push this config file to model

```
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(check_point, config = config)
```

I think this is the only way